# Replace NSLog in the whole project files

Tags: xcode4.5

As all iOS projects, mine has a ton of `NSLogs`. I want to switch to `DLog` since I use a macro for Debug mode. How can I replace `NSLogs` in the whole project by `DLog`? is there any shortcut in Xcode to do so? Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `perl` from the command line (Terminal.app):

```
$ cd /path/to/project/source
$ perl -pi -e 's/NSLog/DLog/' *.m *.mm
```

Comment: Hi, I used instead the shipped option in `Edit/Find/Find And Replace In Workspace`, It does what I want. Thanx for your reply.

Comment: @Malloc where's the fun in that? :D

Comment: I used the code you suggested, it replaces `NSLogs` in almost all files except some files (`.m` files of course). Do you have any idea why some files are not changed?

Comment: @Malloc Are those files in sub-directories?

Comment: Yes, but successfully changed files are also in sub-directories.

Comment: @Malloc not using the above command they aren't unless you use: `perl -pi -e 's/NSLog/DLog/' *.m */*.m`.

Comment: That works, but it's weird. Why accepted in some files and not in others although they are in the same sub-directoy. Any way, thanx :)